# Why won't my KML file display on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

Can anyone tell me why this kml file won't display on google maps?

Im using the following code to add it to the map object which seems to work fine with other kml files.

```
var kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.emotination.com/kml/tasman.kml');
kml.setMap(map);
```

Feed validator says its valid and it isn't too big for googles servers to parse?

The map just zooms right into the ocean!

Comment: This should work, can you post a link to your live code, or put it in a jFiddle?

Comment: It does seem to work now, I tried running it again the next day. Im still confused though because I didn't change anything. All I can think of is that it would be something to do with googles servers cacheing an older copy of the kml file

Comment: You are correct that the kml files are cached. You can get around that problem by add a timestamp parameter to the url (so the google server will consider it as a different file). I.e. 'http://www.emotination.com/kml/tasman.kml?time='+new Date().getTime();

Comment: Please post the gist of the comments as an answer and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to ensure Google's servers aren't displaying a cached copy of your kml file

A good way to do this is to do what [Björn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66419/bjorn) suggests in his comment and just add a timestamp so the end of the url:

```
var kml_tasman = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.emotination.com/kml/tasman.kml?time='+new Date().getTime());
kml_tasman.setMap(map);
```

Comment: After 4 days I find this post - what a life saver.  Thanks nz_karl

Comment: @cymorg can you please mention your code? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @aimal - I just did as suggested by Bjorn & jmb64 in this answer, like this...
newkmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                    url: 'http://www.mybogussite.com/kml/mykmlfile.kml'?time=' + new Date().getTime(),
                    preserveViewport: true,
                    map: map
                });